# how to pop loading panel for a particular control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am working on asp.net and ajax using c#. I am trying to pop loading panel when a user clicks on a button. Mu form contains 3 textboxes and one dropdownlists(autopostback=true) and one submit button. and i use the following code.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>   
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMI" Width="80px" Height="20px" CssClass="s1">                                       </asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMI" Width="80px" Height="20px" CssClass="s1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMI" Width="80px" Height="20px" CssClass="s1"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Dropdownlist ID="drpCountries" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Dropdownlist>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" runat="server" onclick="btnLoad_Click" Text="submit" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and my updateprogress code is:

```
 <asp:UpdateProgress id="updateProgress" runat="server">
     <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/avatarloading.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." style="padding: 10px;position:fixed;top:25%;left:35%;" /><center><span style="color:White;font-weight:bolder;font-size:x-large;"><b>Loading...</b></span></center>
            </div>
     </ProgressTemplate>

</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I need to pop the loading panel when i click on submit button. but it also pops the loading panel when i choose an item in dropdownlist. how could i pop the loading panel when i click on submit button only using ajax. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

two things:
Your DDL does not have the AutoPostBack=true and try modifying the AssociatedUpdatePanelID property of your update progress. It is also possible that the postback is happening extremely fast and you are not able to see whats going on with the update progress. In any event I would check if it's hitting the OnSelectedIndexChanged event and if it is, put the thread to sleep for a couple of seconds and see if you can now see the loading pop up. This is what I have working for myself as a sample project:

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading.....</ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Good luck.